# Vaadin: Bind Enum values to String in Vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

[image: I'm getting some error]I’m working on upgrading our application vaadin version from 7.7.24 to 8.13.3. We’ve completed all the dependency issues and i’m able to start the application in locally.

We have a textbox that is showing up the Event data.

Here is the class file that i'm using:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "changelog")
public class ChangelogEvent extends BaseEntity
{
@Column(name = "remote_ip")
private String remoteIp;
@Column(name = "remote_host")
private String remoteHost;
@Column(name = "event")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private ChangelogEventType eventType;

@Column(name = "entity_type")
private String entityType;

public ChangelogEvent()
{
}
public ChangelogEvent(String remoteIp, String remoteHost, ChangelogEventType eventType)
{
this.remoteIp = remoteIp;
this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
this.eventType = eventType;
}
public String getRemoteIp()
{
return remoteIp;
}
public void setRemoteIp(String remoteIp)
{
this.remoteIp = remoteIp;
}
public ChangelogEventType getEventType()
{
return eventType;
}
public void setEventType(ChangelogEventType eventType)
{
this.eventType = eventType;
}
public String getRemoteHost()
{
return remoteHost;
}
public void setRemoteHost(String remoteHost)
{
this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
}
public String getEntityType()
{
return entityType;
}
public void setEntityType(String entityType)
{
this.entityType = entityType;
}

}
```

And here is my ChangelogEventType.java file that defined ChangelogEventType enum:

```
public enum ChangelogEventType
{
CREATED("Created"),
UPDATED("Updated"),
DELETED("Deleted"),
LOGIN("Login"),
LOGOUT("Logout"),
LOGIN_RETRY("Login Retry"),
ACCOUNT_LOCKED("Account Locked"),
PASSWORD_EXPIRED("Password Expired"),
PASSWORD_CHANGED("Password Changed");
private String text;
ChangelogEventType(String text)
{
this.text = text;
}
public String getText()
{
return text;
}
public static ChangelogEventType fromString(String text)
{
if (text != null)
{
for (ChangelogEventType event : ChangelogEventType.values())
{
if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(event.text))
{
return event;
}
}
}
return null;
}
}
```

Here is the code that i'm using for binding the values into textfield.

```
eventType = createTextField("Event", COLUMN_WIDTH);
binder.forField(eventType)
        .withNullRepresentation("None")
        .bind(ChangelogEvent::getEventType, ChangelogEvent::setEventType);
```

Is there any way to bind the Enum to textbox ?

Comment: Assuming, that you are using a TextField there: your eventType is an
enum in your model but the text-field works with a string. You either
need a proper field, add a converter for the binder, or do the
conversion with the getter/setter on bind.

Comment: That is what my confusion. I'm not able to find a way to convert between string and Enum with vaadin8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write custom converter and use it in `Binder` using `withConverter` method, in your case something like:

```
class StringToChangelogEventTypeConverter implements Converter<String, ChangelogEventType> {
  @Override
  public Result<ChangelogEventType> convertToModel(String fieldValue, ValueContext context) {
    // Produces a converted value or an error
    ChangelogEventType event = ChangelogEventType.fromString(fieldValue);
    if (event != null) {
      // ok is a static helper method that creates a Result
      return Result.ok(ChangelogEventType.fromString(fieldValue));
    } else {
      // error is a static helper method that creates a Result
      return Result.error("Please enter a number");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String convertToPresentation(ChangelogEventType event, ValueContext context) {
    // Converting to the field type should always succeed,
    // so there is no support for returning an error Result.
    return event.getText();
  }
}
```